# How to determine real-world translation estimate from unit vector returned by ‘recoverPose’

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, camera

I am very desperate for some help on this problem: I am implementing a monocular VSLAM system and have currently gotten up to the stages of matching features and descriptors between images, determining the essential matrix and using the recoverPose function to determine the rotation and translation between the images. However, the translation returned is in the form of a unit vector (i.e. is not in mm, cm, m, etc, which is what i want).

Given that I have no external sensors that can be used BUT i have the camera's intrinsic matrix, and a list of tracked features and keypoints, how can I get the actual distance moved?

(Not that it's integral at all, but for the source code: https://github.com/daleksla/salih_slam/blob/master/src/pose.cpp)

Comment: In general, the scale of a landscape cannot be determined from the images taken by a monocular camera.
Therefore, it is necessary to give the SLAM system some information, including the actual scale.

Comment: You need one or more known distances in object space which are seen in the images to retrieve 'global coordinates'.

Answer (score 1):

Monocular slam provides no scale information, and therefore you cannot retrieve metrical translation without additional information about the scene. Examples of such information: the size of an object seen in the scene, the distance between identified points.

In some applications this is a "feature, not a bug". For example, in movie visual effects it's what allows one to composite scale-free synthetic CG on top of the images.

Comment: Gotcha. Quick question - how do Monocular VSLAM implementations, such as ORB-SLAM, do so without any ground-truth information?

Comment: Again, the key is additional information. For example, odometry can provide scale by fixing the camera baseline.